# How to get length of rows and columns in Two-Dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array like following:

```
int[][] array=
{
    {2,3,3},
    {5,6,66}                        
};
```

I want get length of rows and columns:

```
int rows=  // get row length of array
int columns=  // get column length of array
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean upper bounds?

Comment: Please don't use capitals as the first letter of java variable names.

Comment: Especially names that are classes in the JDK!

Comment: upper bound is maximum index of rows and columns

Comment: are number of columns equal in all rows or there can be jagged arrays as well ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important to understand that Java doesn't really have two-dimensional arrays. It has arrays of arrays. That means, for instance, that you can have this:

```
int[][] array=
{
    {1},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {1, 2}
};
```

So there is no **one** upper bound of the second level. Java arrays are inherently jagged, each of the second level in the above has its own length.

So to loop them correctly, you have to check for each of the second-level arrays:

```
int x, y;
int[] second;

for (x = 0; x < array.length; ++x) {
    second = array[x];
    for (y = 0; y < second.length; ++y) {
         // ....
    }
}
```

Full example: [Live Copy](http://ideone.com/clrzKN)

```
public class ArrayExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array=
        {
            {1},
            {1, 2, 3},
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {1, 2}
        };
        int x, y;
        int[] second;

        for (x = 0; x < array.length; ++x) {
          second = array[x];
          for (y = 0; y < second.length; ++y) {
              System.out.println(x + "," + y + ": " + second[y]);
          }
          System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0,0: 1

1,0: 1
1,1: 2
1,2: 3

2,0: 1
2,1: 2
2,2: 3
2,3: 4
2,4: 5

3,0: 1
3,1: 2
```

Or if you don't need the indexes, just the values, you can use the enhanced `for` loop: [Live Example](http://ideone.com/uTXoWm)

```
public class ArrayExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array=
        {
            {1},
            {1, 2, 3},
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {1, 2}
        };

        for (int[] second : array) {
          for (int entry : second) {
              System.out.println(entry);
          }
          System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1

1
2
3

1
2
3
4
5

1
2
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to better understand this, take a look at this image:

[image]

This image is what you call *2D array*, as you can see, it's actually an **array of arrays**.

`nums.length` will return the length of the blue array (which is the number of the rows).
Now if you want to get the number of columns, you should access one row by `nums[0]` for example, and then do `nums[0].length`, which will yield 4.

Now, simply replace `nums` with `array`...

---

**Note**: As you see in the image, the number of columns might differ and it doesn't have to be the same for each row.

Answer (score 0):

In a 2D array there is an array in every place in the first array so you can number of columns by getting the 2D arrays lenght then to get the size of each column you have to go to there place in the 2D array and get the lenght

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.
Suppose a is any 2D array where length of all rows is different.

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
int upperBound0 = array.length - 1; // = 1
int upperBound1 = array[0].length - 1; // = 2
```

As you commented:

upper bound is maximum index of rows and columns

Comment: `array.length - 1;` ?? why `-1`